# AWS Database Encryption for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need database encryption for PHI and Health Records at rest in rails and looked into gems like attr_encrypted. However, I plan to host my Amazon AWS. Does Amazon offer something similar in its S3 bucket or should I code this aspect myself?
PS: I searched SO and http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/ but couldn't make out much from this. Anyone who has experience in aws answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS SQL Server supports [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) for [data at rest](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxTNMLRHD4S1GA/Three-Data-at-Rest-Encryption-Announcements).  The Rails SQL Server adapter is very mature and I would not hesitate to use it.